# How to return ElementFinder from browser.wait() in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my test cases I'm trying to implement helper for check array of elements before return some items. If array does not contains element - I need to wait (I have some troubles with performance of application, sometimes elements in lists are loading too long and synchronization not working).

Function in my helper:

```
getElementFromArray(array, elementIndex) {
    return browser.wait(() => {
        return array.count((count) => {
            return count > elementIndex;
        });
    }, 10000).then(() => {
        return array.get(elementIndex);
    }, () => {
        console.log("Element in array does not exist.");
        return null;
    })
}
```

Then I use it:

```
let row = helper.getElementFromArray(rowsCatalog, indexRow);
row.getText();
```

But I'm getting error, because `browser.wait()` returns `ManagedPromise` instead of `ElementFinder`.

I really do not want to use helpers functions as promises, because it will make the code is very complicated and unreadable (the example above - the simplest case).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable in your case, but you can return after the `browser.wait()`:

```
getElementFromArray(array, elementIndex) {
    browser.wait(() => {
        return array.count((count) => {
            return count > elementIndex;
        });
    }, 10000);

    return array.get(elementIndex);
}
```